# How can I get session data from RedisStore (connect-redis) using SessionID?

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis, socket.io

So the following snippet shows how `RedisStore` is set up and picks up the `sessionID` from incoming GET requests.  However, `sessionStore.get( req.cookies['connect.sid'] )` evaluates to `undefined`.

Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong?  An example `sessionID` that is returned from `req.cookies['connect.sid']` looks like this:

```
s:_8pvC4Zju4GjMOvN6Y4ej8SRVYvopn8C.ctuA/+pQnZt96bLgOW1xizHOLI2nBuH4vzO9Agm26Lk
```

```
var expressSession = require('express-session'); 
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(expressSession);

var sessionStore = new RedisStore({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379});
app.use(expressSession({store: sessionStore,
                        secret: 'xxxx' }));

app.get("/*", function(req, res, next) { 
  if(typeof req.cookies['connect.sid'] !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('sessionID: ', req.cookies['connect.sid']);
    console.log( sessionStore.get(req.cookies['connect.sid'] ));
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Why not use `req.session`? Unless you are wanting to get session data for someone other than the user from the current request?

Comment: I'm trying to get it from sessionStore to authenticate the user with socket.io.

Answer (score 2):

sessionStore.get is a async method, you need pass a callback to this method, like this:

```
sessionStore.get(req.cookies['connect.sid'], function (err, session) {
  console.log(session);
})
```

Watch this docs about [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session#storegetsid-callback).

Comment: Try convert the session data to json to display as key value pair.. 
for ex:
        var data = JSON.parse(session);
        console.log(data["cookie"]); else u ll get string array..